# Null fields in Thymeleaf form using Spring Boot, other fields fine

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, null, thymeleaf

I'm relatively new to Spring Boot. Currently, I'm making a Spring Boot application with user registration system but I've run into an issue. Some of the fields in a form are registering as ‘null’ on the back end, despite the request being posted correctly.

I have a HTML/ Thymeleaf form which submits 8 fields to create a 'User' object. This is the form:

```
<form th:action="@{/users/register_attempt}" th:object="${user}"
      method="post" style="max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto;">
    <div class="m-3">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-4 col-form-label">DOB: </label>
            <div class="col-8">
                <input type="text" th:field="*{dob}" class="form-control" th:required="required" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-4 col-form-label">First Name: </label>
            <div class="col-8">
                <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" class="form-control" th:required="required" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-4 col-form-label">Surname: </label>
            <div class="col-8">
                <input type="text" th:field="*{surname}" class="form-control" th:required="required" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-4 col-form-label">PPSN: </label>
            <div class="col-8">
                <input type="text" th:field="*{ppsn}" class="form-control" th:required="required" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-4 col-form-label">Address: </label>
            <div class="col-8">
                <input type="text" th:field="*{address}" class="form-control" th:required="required" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-4 col-form-label">Phone Number: </label>
            <div class="col-8">
                <input type="number" th:field="*{phone}" class="form-control"  />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-4 col-form-label">E-mail: </label>
            <div class="col-8">
                <input type="email" th:field="*{email}" class="form-control" th:required="required" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-4 col-form-label">Password: </label>
            <div class="col-8">
                <input type="password" th:field="*{password}" class="form-control"
                       required minlength="6" maxlength="10" th:required="required"/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign Up</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And here is the model that the form code is meant to mimic:

```
public class User {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

@NotBlank
private String dob;
@NotBlank
private String name;
@NotBlank
private String surname;
@NotBlank
private String ppsn;
@NotBlank
private String address;
@NotBlank
private String phone;
@NotBlank
@Column(unique = true)
private String email;

private String nextApptId;

private String dose1Date;

private String dose2Date;

private String lastLogin;
@NotBlank
private String password;

public User() {
    super();
}

public User(String dob, String name, String surname, String ppsn, String address, String phone, String email, String password) {
    super();
    this.dob = dob;
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.ppsn = ppsn;
    this.address = address;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
}
 public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getDob() {
    return dob;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getSurname() {
    return surname;
}

public String getPpsn() {
    return ppsn;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getNextApptId() {
    return nextApptId;
}

public void setNextApptId(String apptId) {
    this.nextApptId = apptId;
}

public String getDose1Date() {
    return dose1Date;
}

public void setDose1Date(String dose1Date) {
    this.dose1Date = dose1Date;
}

public String getDose2Date() {
    return dose2Date;
}

public void setDose2Date(String dose2Date) {
    this.dose2Date = dose2Date;
}

public String getLastLogin() {
    return lastLogin;
}

public void setLastLogin(String lastLogin) {
    this.lastLogin = lastLogin;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
}
```

But for some reason I can't figure out, the first four fields - i.e. Dob (date of birth), Name, Surname, and PPSN, are producing a null error when instantiating the user object on the server side, e.g.:

```
     `Resolved [org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 4 errors<EOL>
Field error in object 'user' on field 'dob': rejected value [null]; codes [NotBlank.user.dob,NotBlank.dob,NotBlank.java.lang.String,NotBlank]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [user.dob,dob]; arguments []; default message [dob]]; default message [must not be blank] `.
```

The other four fields, Address, Phone, Email, and Password appear to be working just fine.

As far as I can make out, there it isn't a typo issue (forgive me if that ends up being the case). I have intercepted the Post request using Burp to check that the contents of the fields were making it out of the form and into the request, with the right names for the fields in my User class, and indeed they are all there as intended.

I imagine this means that the issue is coming from how the back end controller code is interpreting this post request based on the model, but I have no real idea of how or where to start. Here is the current controller:

```
@GetMapping("/register")
    public String startRegistration(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", new User());
        return "register";
    }  

@PostMapping("/register_attempt")
    public String registerAttempt(@Valid User newUser) {
        BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        String encodedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(newUser.getPassword());
        newUser.setPassword(encodedPassword);
        userRepository.save(newUser);
        return "registered_successfully";
    }
```

EDIT: Further debugging & clarification with issue persisting

Removing the `@Valid` annotation from the Post Mapping and using old fashioned print statements shows the same results - that the first four fields are null, for no obvious reason.

```
    @PostMapping("/register_attempt")
public String registerAttempt(@ModelAttribute("user") User newUser) {
    System.out.println("Saving user ");
    System.out.println("Name " + newUser.getName());
    System.out.println("Last Name " + newUser.getSurname());
    System.out.println("PPSN " +newUser.getPpsn());
    System.out.println("DOB " +newUser.getDob());
    System.out.println("email " +newUser.getEmail());
    System.out.println("address " +newUser.getAddress());
    System.out.println("encrypted password " +newUser.getPassword());
    System.out.println("Phone num " +newUser.getPhone());
    userRepository.save(newUser);
    System.out.println("User saved");
    return "registered_successfully";
}
```

Using the following dummy data:

[image: The form Pre-submission]

Which sends this Post Request to the back end:

[image: Post Request as captured in burp after submission - all information is there as intended]

Results in these print statements:

```
Saving user 
name null
last Name null
ppsn null
dob null
email foo@bar.com
address Here and there
password password
Phone num 987654321
```

And these error messages:

```
javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [app.model.User] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='must not be blank', propertyPath=surname, rootBeanClass=class app.model.User, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank.message}'}
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='must not be blank', propertyPath=dob, rootBeanClass=class app.model.User, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank.message}'}
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='must not be blank', propertyPath=name, rootBeanClass=class app.model.User, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank.message}'}
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='must not be blank', propertyPath=ppsn, rootBeanClass=class app.model.User, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank.message}'}
]
```

If you have any insight into why this might be happening, I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: Do all of your model properties have getter and setters?

Comment: Hi Josh, yes they do - I removed them from the code above to avoid crowding the post

Comment: Hmm.. I can't reproduce this issue from the model, view and controller.

Comment: Very curious… thanks for checking, will post any updates as I try tame this issue

Comment: Could you please debug the code? Make sure you put a breakpoint at the first line of controller method and see if your user object gets populated properly. Most probably it is not getting populated properly and you hit Validation annotations of the class.

Comment: Hi Ahmet, thanks for replying. The user object is not being populated properly, no - the last four fields are successfully being extracted from the post request and populating the fields in the user object, but the first four fields (despite being contained in the post request in exactly the same way as the last four fields) don't appear to be being used in the instantiation of the user object

Comment: It is weird. Assuming you have public constructors and getter/setter methods then one final thing to try is to remove Valid annotation and putting a RequestBody annotation (i am suggesting this without knowing your controller type rest or standart).

Comment: Good suggestion - currently using standard controller yes, but reworking with a RestController and RequestBody might ultimately be the route I have to go down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `th:object="${user}"` in your Thymeleaf template, so I have to assume that you `@GetMapping` method in your controller has added an instance of `User` to the `Model` using `addAttribute`.

In your `@PostMapping`, you should also use `@ModelAttribute`:

```
@PostMapping("/register_attempt")
public String registerAttempt(@Valid @ModelAttribute("user") User newUser) {
  ...
```

You also need to have setters for each field. I see that `User` has no `setName(String name)`, no `setDob(String dob)`, ...

Some other tips:

1. Do not create `BCryptPasswordEncoder` instances in your controller method itself. When you use Spring Boot, this should be an application wide singleton (Called a bean in Spring lingo). Add a class to your application e.g. `ReservationSystemApplicationConfiguration` which declares this:

```
@Configuration
public class ReservationSystemApplicationConfiguration {
  @Bean
  public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
     return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
  }
}
```

Then in your controller, inject the password encoder:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("...")
public class MyController {

  private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

  public MyController(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
    this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
  }

  @PostMapping("/register_attempt")
  public String registerAttempt(@Valid @ModelAttribute("user") User newUser) {
    String encodedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(newUser.getPassword());
    newUser.setPassword(encodedPassword);
    userRepository.save(newUser);
    return "registered_successfully";
  }
}
```

2. A Controller should not directly call the Repository, but use a Service in between.
3. It is better to use different objects for mapping the form data and for storing the data into the database. See [Form Handling with Thymeleaf](https://www.wimdeblauwe.com/blog/2021/05/23/form-handling-with-thymeleaf/) for more information on how to do that.

Comment: Hi Wim, thanks for your interest. Yes indeed the `@GetMapping` for the landing page adds an instance of `User` to the `Model` using `addAttribute` - I have now included that in the code snippets above for clarity. 

I did as you mentioned and added `@ModelAttribute("user")` within the `@PostMapping`, but no improvement unfortunately! Thanks for the other tips too.

Comment: I updated my answer after you updated your question. You need setters for all properties and the ones that do not work are the ones that do not have setters.

Comment: Thank you Wim, as you said, putting the setters in place has resolved that issue. I appreciate the time you've taken to help me out!